# Determining the local extreme values of a function

Tags: analysis, functions, extreme-value-analysis

I am currently studying analysis and I am facing a problem with understanding how to determine the local extreme values of a function. I just started studying this, but our prof is already giving us mandatory homeworks with extremely hard examples and I am really struggling, if anyone could please help me it would be very helpful.

The function is:

[image]

I would really appreciate the help, I really need it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What criteria have you leaned so far for the extrema of a function?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2-12=0$ $\Rightarrow x=2 $ or $x=-2$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=3y^2-3=0 \Rightarrow  y=1$ or $y=-1$

$(2,1), (2,-1), (-2,1) ,(-2,-1)$ are extreme points

$\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y^2}-(\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial y})^2=36xy$

at point $(2,1) $ $\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2} >0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y^2}-(\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial y})^2=36xy>0$ which means in this point function reaches a local minimum

at point $(-2,-1)$ $\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}< 0 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y^2}-(\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial y})^2=36xy>0 $ that means in this point function reaches a local maximum

and the others are saddle points because $\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y^2}-(\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial y})^2=36xy<0$

Comment: i managed to get until here, and then in class we had to do some stuff like: f''(x,y) = () we put 4 values in 4 corners in between the brackets, then we did f''(2,1) = () and so on for all the extreme points, with different values in the 4 corners inside the brackets, I have no idea what those mean? What would they be in this case? Hope this makes sense

Comment: I have just fixed problems that you mentioned.I hope  my answer is more clear now